# JAVA : file exists Vs searching large xml db

Tags: java, xml, database-design, xml-parsing, file-exists

I'm quite new to Java Programming and am writing my first desktop app, this app takes a unique isbn and first checks to see if its all ready held in the local DB, if it is then it just reads from the local DB, if not it requests the data from isbndb.com and enters it into the DB the local DB is in XML format. Now what im wondering is which of the following two methods would create the least overhead when checking to see if the entry all ready exists.

Method 1.) File Exists.

On creating said DB entry the app would create a seperate file for every isbn number named isbn number.xml (ie. 3846504937540.xml) and when checking would use the file exists method to check if an entry all ready exists using the user provided isbn .

Method 2.) SAX XML Parser.

All entries would be entered into a single large XML file and when checking for existing entries the SAX XML Parser would be used to parse the file and then the user provided isbn would be checked against those in the XML DB for a match.

Note :
The resulting entries could number in the thousands over time.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't use db and where clausule for checking if record exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think either of your methods is all that great. I strongly suggest using a DBMS to store the data. If you don't have a DBMS on the system, or if you want an app that can run on systems without an installed DBMS, take a look at using [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). You can use it from Java with [SQLiteJDBC](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) by David Crawshaw.

As far as your two methods are concerned, the first will generate a huge amount of file clutter, not to mention maintenance and consistency headaches. The second method will be slow once you have a sizable number of entries because you basically have to read (on the average) half the data base for every query. With a DBMS, you can avoid this by defining indexes for the info you need to look up quickly. The DBMS will automatically maintain the indexes.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your speedy replies, i was initially wanting to go without using a DB system, but am now convinced otherwise and will likely use an embedded DB possibly JavaDB (Derby).

Comment: @CourtenayRogers JavaDB/Derby is a nice product. SQLite has posted a detailed [comparison between SQLite and Derby](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteVersusDerby) that may be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like too much the idea of relying on the file system for that task: I don't know how critical is your application, but many things may happen to these xml files :) plus, if the folder gets very very big, you would need to think about splitting these files in some hierarchcal folder structure, to have decent performance.

On the other hand, I don't see why using an xml file as a database, if you need to update frequently.

I would use a relational database, and add a new record in a table for each entry, with an index on the isbn_number column.

If you are in the thousands records, you may very well go with [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/), and you can replace it with a more powerful non-embedded DB if you ever need it, with no (or little :) ) code modification.

Answer (score 0):

Extend your db table to not only include the XML string but also the ISBN number.
Then you select the XML column based on the ISBN column.

Query: Java escaped, `"select XMLString from cacheTable where isbn='"+ isbn +"'"`

A different approach could be to use an **ORM** like **Hibernate**.
In ORM instead of saving the whole XML document in one column you use different different columns for each element and attribute and you could even split upp your document over several tables for a simpler long term design.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better use DBMS instead of your 2 methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you want least overhead just for checking existence, then option 1 is probably what you want, since it's direct look up. Parsing XML each time for checking requires you to to pass through the whole XML file in worst case. Although you can do caching with option 2 but that gets more complicated than option 1.

With option 1 though, you need to beware that there is a limit of how many files you can store under a directory, so you probably have to store the XML files by multiple layer (for example /xmldb/38/46/3846504937540.xml).

That said, neither of your options is good way to store data in the long run, you will find them become quite restrictive and hard to manage as data grows.

People already recommended using DBMS and I agree. On top of that I would suggest you to look into document-based database like MongoDB as your database.